# Mean of dataframe sample pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe df containing more than one column.
I want to groupby using `df.groupby['A']` and corresponding by `'B'` column such that `select n data from 'B'` and store mean every time.
What I tried is
`Sample= df.groupby['A'].agg({'B':np.mean()})` but I don't know how to `select n data from B` every time and then store it's mean.

Comment: Please read this first: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please explain what you mean by `select n data from 'B'`. Do you mean select a random number of values, `n`, from B column? First `n` of B values? Last `n` of B values?

Answer (score 0):

first you can select your corresponding subset from column B assuming 'Category' is your selection criteria by:

```
subB = df[df['B'] == 'Category']
```

than you can apply the group by:

```
grouped_selection = subB.groupby(['A']).mean()

print(grouped_selection)
```

in a one-liner it would look like this:

```
grouped_secection = df[df['B'] == 'Category'].groupby(['A']).mean()
```